# Transferring Between Lines

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

In Cities In Motion 1, you could put two stops from two different lines next to each other and people would automatically know that they can get off at that stop and go to the other line if necessary, for example if line 1 covers the north part of the city and line 2 covers the east part, and someone on the north side wants to get to the east side.

This doesn't seem to be happening (for me at least) in CIM 2.  Is this something that needs to be explicitly done in the game, like saying, you are allowed to transfer between line 1 and 2, or is this not supported anymore or something?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything special to allow passengers to transfer lines.  If it's not working for you, it's a bug.

Bear in mind, however, that you have to have a lot of coverage to get people to want to use your service over long distances/multiple lines.  If you only have two lines in total you won't get many passengers at all, let alone transfers.  The commuters just want to get from point A to point B, and if your system doesn't have a way for them to do that, they'll drive or walk.